# Amazon S3 Public Dataset Notifications

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

The documentation for Amazon S3 bucket notification states that you must have owner privileges on the bucket in order to configure notifications. Additionally, the manner in which notifications are configured doesn't lend itself to anonymous subscribers.

My question is whether it is possible to subscribe to notifications for a public dataset bucket in S3, and if not, whether there are any alternatives available to polling the objects list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the recently launched [Data Exchange](https://aws.amazon.com/data-exchange/) service, which makes it easy to find, subscribe to, and use third-party data in the cloud.

> The Data Provider can revise their data sets at any time. **The Data Consumer receives a CloudWatch Event each time a product that they are subscribed to is updated**; this can be used to launch a job to retrieve the latest revision of the assets.

This AWS [solution](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/find-and-acquire-new-data-sets-and-retrieve-new-updates-automatically-using-aws-data-exchange/) automates retrieval of new revisions.

Comment: That looks perfect, except the dataset I'm looking for doesn't appear to publish on Data Exchange.